# Trying to have separate fail_under values for different modules in monorepo using coverage.py

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, monorepo, coverage.py

The problem is basically summed up by the title but simply put, I am implementing coverage requirements for a mono-repo codebase that is maintained by multiple teams.

Contraints:

- All of our utilities run from the root directory, including our tests.
- Running our tests runs all of the tests for all of the modules unless otherwise explicitly specified which services to run.
- Running test coverage is currently only limited by the files omitted in my .coveragerc file which essentially looks like this (where for example we want to run coverage on `src/service_c/*`:

```
[run]
omit = 
    *__init__.py*,
    */tests/*
    src/service_a/*,
    src/service_b/*,
```

I have added fail_under criteria for our coverage check of service_c, but if we decide at some point that service_a should also have fail_under criteria, then I want that to be exclusive from the fail_under criteria of service_c.

Without having to break all of these services apart, is there a way I can do this with coverage.py?

Answer (score 0):

Coverage.py doesn't provide this as a feature, but I wrote a simple tool to measure goals like this more flexibly: [Coverage goals](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202111/coverage_goals.html).  It will do what you want, and could become a coverage.py feature in the future.